# Edit and package DNN module without solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I've recently been given a DotNetNuke module to edit and publish back to the website. However the module folder that I have been given is missing the visual studio solution file. It has all the individual cs files so I can open them up one by one but there is no overall file for the module, and so I'm not sure how I can then repackage and deploy the changes once I've completed them.

I have tried creating a blank solution to add the project to but I get an error when I try to do this that goes like:

*Unable to read the project file '...csproj'. The imported project "....nuget\nuget.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the < Import > declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk*

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module might have been built as a WSP type project where there is no compiled DLL and .NET just compiles the files in place. If you got a module package, you should be able to install the module into a DotNetNuke site, add the module to a page and then just make changes to the files within the App_Code and DesktopModules folders and refresh the page to see the changes.

When you're done, you can either just copy the updated files into the zip package or, you can go to Host -> Extensions. Then edit the module and from the Manage Menu select "Create Package" and it will generate a new Package.

Comment: Ah right, so just copying the files into the right DesktopModules folder will be enough? What happens if one of the files has a name change, will it cause an error as it will be looking for the old name or will it just adapt to it?

Comment: If one of the files has a name change, you will probably need to go into the module definition and update the referenced control in Module Controls section and then regenerate the Package. Or, you can just manually modify the manifest file which is a pretty easy to understand XML file.